# How to do prediction using trained and stored tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I have an existing trained model (specifically tensorflow word2vec https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb). I restore the existing model well enough:

```
model1 = tf.train.import_meta_graph("models/model.meta")
model1.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("model/"))
```

But I don't know how to use the newly loaded (and trained) model to make predictions. How do I do predictions with a restored model?

Edit:

model code from the official tensorflow repo https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you are loading the checkpoint I assume this should be the best way to use it for inference.

Load the placeholders:

```
input = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Placeholders/placeholder_name:0")
....
```

Load the op you use to perform prediction:

```
prediction = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("SomewhereInsideGraph/prediction_op_name:0")
```

Create a session, execute the prediction op, and feed data in the placeholders.

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={input:input_data})
```

On the other hand, what I prefer to do is always create have the whole model creation inside a constructor of a class. Then, what I would do is the following:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
model = ModelClass()
loader = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
loader.restore(sess, path_to_checkpoint_dir)
```

Since you want to load the embeddings from a trained word2vec model in another model, you should do something like:

```
embeddings_new_model = tf.Variable(...,name="embeddings")
embedding_saver = tf.train.Saver({"embeddings_word2vec": embeddings_new_model})
with tf.Session() as sess:
    embedding_saver.restore(sess, "word2vec_model_path")
```

Assuming that the embeddings variable in the word2vec model is named `embeddings_word2vec`.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! However I have one more issue. I don't have a lot of experience with tf (mostly used keras) and I don't know what command I should use to calculate the prediction, especially for the word2vec model. The code is linked to the original question. Can you also suggest how to get a prediction with that model?

Comment: I had a look at the code. Word2vec (implemented with Skipgram), is not a model that you can use to make predictions in the exact sense. Usually, what you would do in this case, is load the pretrained `embedding` matrix into another model, and initialize the other model's embedding matrix with the loaded values.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Use the embedding as a "seed" for a new model?

Comment: Hi, that's not exactly it. I already store the embeddings once training is finished, I just want to generate new embeddings. How can I use the existing rudimentary nn and weights to calculate a new embedding?

Comment: You can't. The word2vec model is not something that you use to make predictions on unseen examples. What you can do, on the other hand, is retrieve the learned embeddings for the samples that the word2vec model has already seen, and use them for your specific use case. Read more about the word2vec (skip-gram, cbow) to see how it should be used.

Comment: I have weights and biases from the model. I have the embedding of my original batch and then I make some changes to my word and want to find the new embedding. Can't I use the weights and bias to get the new embedding?

Comment: The embeddings your model has learned are just for the words the model has seen during the training phase. The size of the embedding matrix is equal to the number of words. Therefore, once you load the model, you can only retrieve an embedding for the words the model has seen(learned the embeddings for), during the training phase.